# Codeigniter - Undefined variable: id

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I don't know where's the error but it always shows undefined variable.
Here's my code:

Model

```
class profile_info extends CI_Model {

    public function get_profile_information($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('accountSystem', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row(); 
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class home extends CI_Controller {

    public function display_name()
    {
        $this->load->model('profile_info');
        $data['profile'] = $this->profile_info->get_profile_information($id);
        $this->load->view('account_info_view', $data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Account Information</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $profile->name; ?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The function display_name()  is using the variable $id but do not see  how this variable gets into that function??   You cannot use something thats not existing in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In the `display_name()` function I didn't see any parameter being passed (in this case, it's `$id`).

So eventually the `$id` variable `$this->profile_info->get_profile_information($id)` will appears undefined. Give `display_name()` function a parameter.

Ex: `display_name($id) {...}`.

Comment: Thank youuu. I already added a parameter but right now it says "Too few arguments to function home::display_name(),"

Comment: @RommelVerterraTraya Add parameters to where that function is being called and your problem will be resolved.
If it's URL problem in your case then add an user id like `domain.com/home/display_name/$id`.